# Is it possible to create a word preprocessor with a plugin?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I am wondering whether it is possible to create a plugin that would act as a kind of a word-preprocessor.

Here is an example to make things more clear:

Let's say I want to be able to highlight words or sentences. But I want to do this using a custom syntax, like `<red>text</red>`. I know this can be easily achieved with syntax definitions.

However, I am also searching for a way to *hide* the syntax part itself, aka. the `<red>` and `</red>` from the view. This would leave only red `text` visible within the editor.

So, when the file is loaded, the syntax is hidden and the words are highlighted. When file is saved, the syntax is saved as well.

Is this possible to achieve through a plugin? If so, which functions/methods should I look for?

Comment: No, this is not possible with Sublime. It is a *text* editor, meaning that it edits plain text files and shows their complete contents. You can edit markup, like HTML, XML, Markdown, etc., but it does not parse that markup and display the rendered version. There are plenty of other programs and IDEs that do that for you, though.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about it that way..